# Error when putting implemented generics within a set

Tags: c#, generics

I want to have generic types in my code to allow for multiple uses with different contexts, as usual. As an example I built a simpler version of what I want which has the same problem.

The generic classes:

```
class GenericBase<T>
{
    public T item { get;  }

    public GenericBase(T item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }
}

class GenericOuter<T>
{
    private readonly GenericBase<T> single;
    private readonly ISet<GenericBase<T>> baseSet;

    public GenericOuter(GenericBase<T> single, ISet<GenericBase<T>> baseSet)
    {
        this.single = single;
        this.baseSet = baseSet;
    }
}
```

I want to implement `GenericBase<T>` like this:

```
class ConcreteBase : GenericBase<int>
{
    ConcreteBase(int item) : base (item) { }
}
```

Which works fine.
And I also want to implement `GenericOuter<T>` like this:

```
class ConcreteOuter : GenericOuter<int>
{
    ConcreteOuter(ConcreteBase single, ISet<ConcreteBase> items) : base(single, items) { }
}
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
CS1503: Argument 2: Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet<namespace.ConcreteBase>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet<namespace.GenericBase<int>>'
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Isn't this a simple case of class inheritance?

It works for Argument 1 which is the same type but without being in a Set.

Comment: No they're not the same thing. Lets say you would create a second class `SecondConcreteBase: GenericBase<int>`. You would be allowed to add that to an `ISet<GenericBase<int>>` but not to an `ISet<ConcreteBase>`, I hope this shows you why you can't cast an `ISet<ConcreteBase>` to an `ISet<GenericBase<int>>` they're just not the same thing. Look up covariance, contravariance and invariance if you want to know more about what is actually going on and why certain casts are or aren't allowed.

Comment: I understand what you mean. In some way I have to restrict the class to a certain type and only accept one implementation of that type. Thank you!

Comment: [`ISet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1?view=netcore-3.1) has invariant generic type parameter, therefore it doesn't work. You should use exactly the same type as type parameter. [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1) has covariant type parameter, it might work in your case (haven't checked that)